# Custom keyboard with custom row

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

[image]I have to draw custom view (image view + edit text) on top of keyboard in my custom keyboard app. how can i draw this?
I used many custom keyboard example but using that i was just able to draw custom keys (Alphabets/Numeric).

Please help me

Edit-

I tried to create with custom keyboard and added a sample view above keyboardview but when i run the app it is not visible

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/layoit_row"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivKeyboard"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:scaleType="fitEnd"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

    <EditText android:id="@+id/et_box"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivKeyboard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="Asjhish"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
    android:id="@+id/keyboard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/layoit_row"
    android:keyPreviewLayout="@layout/preview" />
```

Comment: post screenshot of the desired result

Comment: @RahulKhurana : please see attached image

Comment: @AshishAgrawal in that case you have create custom keyboard were you can create UI like above , clone any keyboard code and create custom layout . You cannot do any changes to google keyboard

Comment: @ShanmugamI tried with custom keyboard but view which i am adding at top not displaying at runtime

Comment: @AshishAgrawal put that keyboard view also inside Relativelayout

Comment: Put everything inside single parent

Comment: @ShanmugamDid not work

Comment: @AshishAgrawal did you change the system keyboard to your keybord?

Comment: yes @Shanmugam i did change

Comment: @AshishAgrawal check this guthub link for reference https://github.com/blackcj/AndroidCustomKeyboard  , i cloned this keyboard and added custom view , it is working